# Decomposition of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix. Can we always find two vectors $a,b\in \mathbb C^n$ such that $A=a\otimes b^T$?

Comment: Have you tried it for, say, $n=2$?

Comment: It seems like you should write either $ab^T$ or $a \otimes b$ instead of $a \otimes b^T$. At least it looks that way here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product

Comment: On second thought, if you mean the Kronecker product, then it's OK, but it does look strange to find this $\otimes$ sign in such a simple vector-and-vector situation.

Comment: What's the rank of $ab^T$?

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. For example, you will never be able to write the identity matrix as such a product. The rank of the resulting matrix is $1$ (or $0$), this is a consequence of the inequality
$$\mathrm{rank}(AB) \le \min\left(\rm{rank}(A),\ \rm{rank}(B)\right)$$
So necessarily all matrices with rank $2$ or more will not be expressible. However, all rank one matrices *can* be written as such a product. This is a special case of the more general [rank factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization).